# How can I get the iteration of the first array index in a map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

In the following code curveData is a 2 dimensional array. How can I get the iteration of the first array index in a map?

```
curveData.map(function(d) { 
    return d.map(function(count, j) { 
        console.log('d:'+d+', j:'+j+', count:'+count);
        return {x:j, y:count, y0:0};
    });
});
```

In the code above j is the secondary index.

For example:

```
curveData[i][j]
```

I am getting the j iteration but how can I access the i iteration?

Comment: Are you wanting the index of the outer `map`? If so you just need to add the index to the parameters `curveData.map(function(d, i) { `

Comment: Oh, is that it? Let me go test.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! If you post an answer I'll chose it as the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the outer index, you just need to include the index parameter in your top level `map`:

```
curveData.map(function(d, i) { 
    return d.map(function(count, j) { 
        console.log(curveData[i][j]);
        console.log('d:'+d+', j:'+j+', count:'+count);
        return {x:j, y:count, y0:0};
    });
});
```